# How do I manipulate an array to compute total score

Tags: php, arrays

Given each grade a score as shown below.

```
A1 = 6,
B2 = 5,
B3 = 4,
C4 = 3,
C5 = 2,
C6 = 1
D7 = 0.5
```

I have an array that contains a student result to compute the result weight.
The array is given below

```
       Array ( 
          [s1] => Yoruba 
          [s1_score] => C4 
          [s2] => Agricultural Science 
          [s2_score] => B3 
          [s3] => Chemistry 
          [s3_score] => C4 
          [s4] => Biology 
          [s4_score] => B3 
          [s5] => Physics 
          [s5_score] => C4 
          [s6] => Further Mathematics 
          [s6_score] => B3 
          [s7] => Economics 
          [s7_score] => D7 
          [s8] => English 
          [s8_score] => B2 
          [s9] => Mathematics 
          [s9_score] => B3 
          [std_id] => HFT199988 
        );
```

I want the output to be the addition of the score of each grade in the result.
e.g c4 (3) + A1 (6) .....
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a real question? Can you show your own attempt?

Comment: Why is your data keyed like that? doesn't seem very useful. Look,you're going to have to manually loop over your data, perform some string manipulation on the key to re-group the data, before you can even think of adding the scores together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? I've kept it easy.

```php
$scoresNum = 0;
$scoresSum = 0;
foreach($studentRow as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, '_score') !== false) { // check if the key contains _score
        ++$scoresNum; // add 1 to $scoresNum
        $scoresSum += $value; // add the value to $scoresSum
        // or $scoresSum += scoreArray[$value]; if key=D7 and referring to another array
    }
}

echo $scoresNum . ' scores, ' . $scoresSum . ' total score, ' . ($scoresSum/$scoresNum) . ' avarage score.';
```